# Use for loop index in string Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need it iterate through different objects while making forms at the same time and the way I thought of handling the submit was to use this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm{{u}}()">
```

The issue is that I cannot figure out how to get the index (u) to get into the string without throwing an error.

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
```

I know that

```
(ngSubmit)={{u}}
```

Would work but I also need the function name.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need **`{{}}`** as the error says , it should be

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitForm(u)">
```

Comment: would this work for what I need to do with getting data from multiple different forms or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple forms ?

Comment: I have a list of users that when edited need to be saved to the data base and I have it so that each one creates a form for them self my plan was that when confirm is clicked I would handle the logic in the .ts file my only issue is I'm not sure how to get the data back and forth. I am starting to think this is the wrong way of going about this

Comment: go for dynamic forms here is the link https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form. Where you will get the values attribute to save the data